# Python How to find a key in a nested dict

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python, json

I am currently automating an application that is available across multiple platforms. We have a common JSON file per page denoting the elements locator as below:

```
{
"XYZ": {
    "default": "xpath=//*[@id='root']",
    "iOS": "css=#name",
    "android": "name=//*[@class='android.widget.']",
    "web": "id=testing",
    "mobileWeb": "class=mobileLogin",
    "test":""
},
 "ABC": {
    "default": "xpath=//*[@id='root']/cyz",
    "android": "name=//*[@class='android.widget.']",
    "web": "id=testing",
    "mobileWeb": "class=mobileLogin",
    "test":""
} }
```

Assuming the platform is iOS, I can retrieve the locator for XYZ, `data['XYZ']['iOS]`. I cannot do the same for `ABC` because the locator for `iOS` is not defined. In this case, I need to pick the value for the `default` one.

The challenge here is to find out if `iOS` is defined for ABC or not. How should I approach?

Comment: You get it just like the one with a platform, `my_dict["xyz"]["default"]`. What's that different from `my_dict["xyz"]["iOS"]`?

Comment: @pavelsaman I have edited the question for more clarity. The idea is to first see if there is a locator defined for the platform(e.g iOS) and if not get the default value.

Comment: Ok, I posted one option as an answer. See for yourself if this works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are certain that `XYZ` and the default value will always be in the dict, you can use [`get()` method](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/dictionary_get.htm) like so:

```python
my_dict = {
    "XYZ": {
        "default": "xpath=//*[@id='root']",
        "iOS": "css=#name",
        "android": "name=//*[@class='android.widget.']",
        "web": "id=testing",
        "mobileWeb": "class=mobileLogin",
        "test":""
    }
}

my_dict_default = {
    "XYZ": {
        "default": "xpath=//*[@id='root']",        
        "android": "name=//*[@class='android.widget.']",
        "web": "id=testing",
        "mobileWeb": "class=mobileLogin",
        "test":""
    }
}

print(my_dict.get("XYZ").get("iOS", my_dict["XYZ"]["default"]))
print(my_dict_default.get("XYZ").get("iOS", my_dict_default["XYZ"]["default"]))
```

The first print statement will give you `css=#name`, the second will give you the default value `xpath=//*[@id='root']`.

There are multiple other approaches you can find e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16003408/how-to-use-dict-get-with-multidimensional-dict